# Customizing ServiceAuthorizationManager for WCF Issue

Tags: c#, wcf, asp.net-mvc-4

I have created custom ServiceAuthorizationManager as "CustomUserNamePasswordValidator" for my WCF project. below is the snippet of my project. I want my wcf to call up this authorication class before it actually start calling on WCF API but this is not happening. My "Login" WCF API is calling paraller to this authorization class. so when there is call by client to Login it calls both 
"CustomUserNamePasswordValidator" and Login method simultaneously.

**Authorization Class**

```
 public class CustomUserNamePasswordValidator : ServiceAuthorizationManager
 {
    HttpRequestMessageProperty httpProperties;
    string operationName;

    protected override bool CheckAccessCore(OperationContext operationContext)
    {
        operationName = GetOperationName(operationContext);
        httpProperties = (HttpRequestMessageProperty)operationContext.IncomingMessageProperties["httpRequest"];
        string authHeader = httpProperties.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization];

        string subno = string.Empty;
        string password = string.Empty;
        string version = string.Empty;
        string credntialType = string.Empty;

            string[] credentials = authHeader.Split(':');
            credntialType = credentials[0];

               password = credentials[1];

                if (!AuthorizeUser(password))
                {
                    throw new ArgumentException("401:Token invalid or expired.(0x000)");                        
                }
            }
       }

     private int AuthenticateUser(string subno, string pin, string version)
      {
      }
  }
```

**WCF Client Service Snippet**

```
public class ClientService : IClientService
{
    public wsLoginResult LoginUser()
    {
            HttpRequestMessageProperty httpReqProps = (HttpRequestMessageProperty)OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageProperties["httpRequest"];
            string res = httpReqProps.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization];

            foreach (var item in res.Split(':'))                
                ActivityLog("Activity", "Login Steps", item, item); 
    }
}
```

**Web.Config Snippet**

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<connectionStrings>
 <add name="wmas_subsConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=WT;Initial Catalog=wmas;User ID=sa;Password=ra3?" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
 </connectionStrings>
 <system.web>
  <compilation targetFramework="4.5" debug="true"/>
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
 </system.web>
 <system.serviceModel>
  <client>
  <endpoint  address="http://192.168.1.12:7002/MobileApplicationWS/MobileApplicationApiWSImplService"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="MobileApplicationApiWSPortBinding"
            contract="VASService.MobileApplicationApiWS"
            name="MobileApplicationApiWSPort" />

 </client>
 <services>
  <service name="ClientService.ClientService" behaviorConfiguration="ClientService.ServiceBehavior">
    <endpoint address=""
              binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webHttpBindingConfiguration"
              contract="ClientService.IClientService" behaviorConfiguration="webBehaviour"/>
    <endpoint address="stream"
              binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webHttpBindingConfigurationStreamed"
              contract="ClientService.IClientService" behaviorConfiguration="webBehaviour"/>
    <endpoint address="mex"
              binding="mexHttpsBinding"
              contract="IMetadataExchange" />        
   </service>
 </services>
 <bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="MobileApplicationApiWSPortBinding" />
  </basicHttpBinding>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="webHttpBindingConfiguration" />
    <binding name="webHttpBindingConfigurationStreamed" transferMode="StreamedResponse" />
  </webHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ClientService.ServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
      <serviceAuthorization serviceAuthorizationManagerType="ClientService.CustomUserNamePasswordValidator, ClientService" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="webBehaviour">
      <webHttp/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
 </behaviors>
 <protocolMapping>
  <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https"/>
  </protocolMapping>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
  </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
 <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
 <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
 </system.webServer>
  </configuration>
```

Comment: Is this a restful service or SOAP? Please include more from your web.config

Comment: please see modified post for web.config .

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your solution doesn't work is that `CustomUserNamePasswordValidator` can't be used in a RESTful service. Take a look at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa354513(v=vs.110).aspx

The example uses SOAP and defines the behaviour of the endpoint which activates `serviceAuthorization` tag. If you don't define the security of the endpoint the `serviceAuthorization` simply won't work.

```
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <!-- username binding -->
    <binding name="Binding">
      <security mode="Message">
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

In a RESTful service there is no `SecurityMode = Message`, there are only 3: None/Transport/TransportCredentialOnly. Read on about it here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb924478(v=vs.110).aspx

`clientCredentialType="UserName"` is only available in Message.

You can try defining the endpoint security mode to: Transport and then the credential type to: Basic/Certificate/Digest/None/Ntlm/Windows, but seeing as your solution is none of these not sure how well that will work.

There is (I think) a better way of doing authentication if you are extracting headers and not using any "approved" way. Try implementing  an extension service: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.iparameterinspector(v=vs.110).aspx

Good Luck!